# Laravel TokenMismatchError in Production (Login)

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, composer-php, forge

I just updated ubuntu packages and composer update from inside my ssh terminal on Forge

Now when I try to login I get TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 68)

I have tried

- deleted browsers cookies and application data
- php artisan clear:cache
- composer dump-autoload
- Deleted composer.lock on both sides, updated from homestead and git push to server
- php artisan clear-compiled
- Restarted Nginx, Server

I am running out of ideas now. What can I do to fix this??

Thanks

Comment: Is the .env URL set to localhost/whatever-not-production-url?

Comment: is login AJAX or a form?

Comment: I believe the urls are working fine. I can login no prob in development mode

Comment: I am using Ajax (Axios) to submit a form, which delegates to a PHP controller to check the password etc. I am binding the crsf-token to an input with Vue - 
`<input type="hidden" name="csrf-token" :value="csrfToken">

 computed: {
  csrfToken() {
         return $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
  }
 }
`

Comment: Have you tried generating a new key? `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: when you post to the controller, in the data are you passing `_token` or in the headers passing `X-CSRF-TOKEN`

Comment: Haven't tried key:generate from production. Is that safe? Not sure what token I am passing. Investigating. Haven't looked at the csrf in a while

Comment: I can't even reach `    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->all();` it stops at VerifyCSRFToken error

Comment: Middleware runs before controller functions. As a note on regenerating the key, DO NOT do it if you already have encrypted data stored in the DB.

Comment: I am lead to believe this is a mismatch betweer composer.lock files on homestead and server. Thoughts?

Comment: composer lock should remain the same when deploying. When you move to production, did you do a `composer update` or `composer install`

Comment: I foolishly ran a composer update in production. Now I am trying to fix with a composer install, and dump-autoload but its not working

Comment: should I rm /storage/framework/sessions/* ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153462/discussion-between-mbozwood-and-dazzle).

Answer (score 1):

After discussion, it was a folder permissions issues.

`chmod 777 -R storage`

OP must be careful with this as it opens up the server.

More appropriate for production would be the following:

`sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache 
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache`

Answer (score 0):

chmod 777 -R storage was enough to enable log in, but it brought other issues. Users could not post images for example.

This is eventually what worked for me -

ssh

Check if forge is set as the user $ ps -aux | grep "php"

if you get www-data instead of forge, you might have the same problem as me and need to set forge as the user instead of www-data

$ sudo chown -R forge:www-data /home/forge/mysite.com

$ sudo chmod -R 770 /home/forge/mysite.com

Everything works as expected for me again

Back to pretending like I know what I'm doing!! :D